# getting the Mouseover Event on listview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, listviewitem

I had created the listview in below manner

using grid view init;

i need that when mouseover on the gridview item i need to get that username details in the popup window , i am able to generate the popupwindow
except that Hover username in the listview

this is my sample code so please try to provide this information

```
<ListView AlternationCount="2" removed="#FFB6CCD8" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="77" FontSize="13" Height="43" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="checkedListView1" SelectionMode="Single" TabIndex="2" Width="269" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemDataTemplate}"
                 SelectionChanged="checkedListView_SelectionChanged" MouseEnter="checkedListView1_MouseEnter" MouseMove="checkedListView1_MouseMove">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=empid}" Header="CardID" Width="1" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=username}" Width="200" />
                         <GridViewColumn >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="/WPF.Themes.Demo;component/Images/Status-user-online.ico" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

here  i am  using the listview in the Gridview  manner , so  please  try to  provide the  Information to  get the Username which  was  presented in the Gridviewcolumn when  mouse cursor  Hover in the listview

Thank you.

Comment: there is  no that  type of event  like  mouse houre  so  that  i am  asking for the idea